# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException Appium with webview context

Tags: android, webview, appium, native, nosuchelementexception

**We are creating autotests with Appium for Android app. Our app has a few webview pages.
After redirection to the webview page - I changed the context but still cant work with webview elements.**

```
    @test
    @DisplayName("DAF-T14 Check feedback form after clicking it from profile page")
    public void ProfileAppFeedbackFlow() throws Exception {

    String expectedFeedbackTitle = "Feedback";
    String expectedFeedbackWebTitle = "What are your experiences with the DKV app?";
    String expectedDescription = "You have noticed incorrect station information? Please repor";

    var onboardingPage = new OnboardingPage();
    var onboardingLinearLayout = onboardingPage.clickSkipButton();
    var locationPopUp = onboardingLinearLayout.clickLaterButton();
    var analysisPopUp = locationPopUp.clickAllowAllTimeButton();
    analysisPopUp.clickActivateButton();
    var feedbackProfilePage = new DoYouLikePopUp().clickNoButton();
    Assertions.assertEquals(feedbackProfilePage.getFeedbackTittle(), expectedFeedbackTitle);
```

**Now I'm checking and changing the context to webview**

```
    Set strcontext = null;
    try{
    strcontext = ((AndroidDriver) AppiumInit.getAppiumDriver()).getContextHandles();
    System.out.println("Found contexts size: '" + strcontext.size() + "'");
    for (String s :strcontext) {
    System.out.println("Found context: '" + s + "'");
    if (s != null && s.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
    System.out.println("Switching context to: '" + s + "'");
    ((AndroidDriver) AppiumInit.getAppiumDriver()).context(s);
    break;
    }
    }
    } catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Checking if the context is webview**

```
    String currentContext = ((AndroidDriver) AppiumInit.getAppiumDriver()).getContext();
    System.out.println("Current Context: " + currentContext);
```

**and checking the title text**

```
   Assertions.assertEquals(feedbackProfilePage.getFeedbackWebTitl(), expectedFeedbackWebTitle);
```

**where**

```
    public String getFeedbackWebTitl() {
    WebElement feedbackWebTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='title']"));
    return feedbackWebTitle.getText();
    }
```

**What can I see in logs:**

```
Found contexts size: '2'
Found context: 'NATIVE_APP'
Found context: 'WEBVIEW_com.dkveuroservice.mobileappkit'
Switching context to: 'WEBVIEW_com.dkveuroservice.mobileappkit'
Current Context: WEBVIEW_com.dkveuroservice.mobileappkit
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@id='title']"}
(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.71)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.5.1', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [629bae0e-84be-463f-86a7-49e1c58ddbcb, findElement {using=xpath, value=//span[@id='title']}]
Capabilities {appium:app: //Users//nifargo//Documents..., appium:appActivity: com.dkveuroservice.mobileap..., appium:appPackage: com.dkveuroservice.mobileap..., appium:automationName: UiAutomator2, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {app: //Users//nifargo//Documents..., appActivity: com.dkveuroservice.mobileap..., appPackage: com.dkveuroservice.mobileap..., automationName: UiAutomator2, deviceName: autoTests, newCommandTimeout: 800, platformName: ANDROID}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 33, appium:deviceManufacturer: Google, appium:deviceModel: sdk_gphone64_arm64, appium:deviceName: emulator-5554, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 560, appium:deviceScreenSize: 1440x2560, appium:deviceUDID: emulator-5554, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:newCommandTimeout: 800, appium:pixelRatio: 3.5, appium:platformVersion: 13, appium:statBarHeight: 84, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:viewportRect: {height: 2392, left: 0, top: 84, width: 1440}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: ANDROID}
Session ID: 629bae0e-84be-463f-86a7-49e1c58ddbcb
changed

**LOGs**
https://gist.github.com/Nifargo/2920de27ba7ea76625f7430a6bf6bf96

Expect that i can chech the text of web element